# Passing parameters via Force.com Site URL

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

I have a Force.com site (https://mycompany.com/Signup). A VF page called 'CustomerSignup' has been created and configured as the home page of this site which is used to sign up customers.

I want to pass some parameters with this Site URL which I can use in my VF Page to autofill some of the fields on the page

Is it possible for force.com sites? how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is completely possible and follows the same guidelines as any other URL.

Construct URL:

```
https://mycompany.com/Signup
```

Add params

```
https://mycompany.com/Signup?param1&param2&param3
```

How you construct it and how you consume it all depends on your use case and requirements.

You can use the standard `$CurrentPage.parameter` on the page to do something or use a customer extension or controller.

Follows all the same criteria as any VF page and has access to the underlying data that you give permissions to for the Guest user. **Be Careful here**

Comment: Thanks Eric! So I am passing these params to the Site URL but these can be consumed by the VF Page (Home page). Is that right ?

Comment: Just like any other page. Nothing special about Force.com sites. Your comment is way to specific without knowing the details. As long as you understand visual force and the parameters nothing is different

Comment: Tried to make my question little more specific. Does that help?

Comment: No. what I meant was your comment "can be consumed by the VF Page (Home page)" no way of knowing how you set it up so all I can say is generally yes. Again, nothing different than VF in full salesforce. As for autofill, best bet is to add a controller to populate those values from the params

Comment: ok Thanks! I think you already answered. It makes sense to me now. My VF Page is a very simple page with few input fields and a Save button